# How to add jpanel form to a jpanel on runtime in java?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, validation, repaint

```
NewProductPanel pPanel=new NewProductJPanel();
pPanel.setVisible(true);
mainPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
mainPanel.add(pPanel);
```

i have created a jPanel form and i want to add it dynamically to my program's mainJFrame, i am using NetBeans..plz help me regarding this..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, don't call `setVisible` on pPanel, call it on mainPanel. Also, you may need to call `revalidate` on mainPanel.

Comment: Thanks this just worked:  `pPanel.setVisible(true);`      
        `mainPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());`
        `mainPanel.add(pPanel);`
        
      `mainPanel.validate();`

Comment: @AlAmmar: you will want to listen to what Bill is telling you and follow his advice as it is correct.